# Return 'NameError' instead of 'Pass' when Can't find element

Tags: python, selenium, nameerror, nosuchelementexception

I am using Python Selenium. When I try this:

```
try:
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('--path--').text.encode('ascii','ignore')
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass


print element
```

But, when element does not exist, shown error

```
NameError: name 'element' is not defined
```

..when it should just `pass` when can't find the element.

Comment: Python/Selenium/WebDriver/WebBrowser version information please?

Comment: Python 2.7.14
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
*But, I thought mostly about `try`, `except` rules that I overlooked.

Comment: So, just put `print element` into `try` block

Comment: I have many `try` block. Need to print together. *Rakesh below solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you are setting the element in the try part only. Either set `'element'` outside `try-except or in except`.

**Ex:**

```
try:
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('--path--').text.encode('ascii','ignore')
except NoSuchElementException:
    element = None
```

Comment: Ok. Thank you Rakesh. I just put `None` before.

Answer (score 0):

As per the `try {}` block in your code block when the element is not there *exception* is raised :

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('--path--').text.encode('ascii','ignore')
```

Here the variable **element** is never gets initialized.

The exception is handled in the `catch {}` block where you just pass it as follows :

```
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass
```

Hence moving forward when you try to `print()` the variable **element** as follows :

```
print element
```

You see the *Python* error as :

```
NameError: name 'element' is not defined
```